# Jobs going in queue on free nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub

I am trying to submit a job on my cluster using qsub but the job seems to be going in queue even when the nodes are free. I had submitted some jobs a couple of days ago using the same job submission script on the same nodes and everything was working fine then. Can someone suggest something which can help me in submitting the jobs?

Comment: What scheduler are you using? TORQUE doesn't start the jobs until something (usually a scheduler) tells it to start them.

Comment: The problem got sorted out by restarting pbs_mom..Thanks for your support anyways..